# I've uninstalled Xubuntu but the Ubuntu bootmanager still shows up win11?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu, bootloader

As the title says I've uninstalled Xubuntu but the bootmanager still shows up everytime I boot. How do I fix that.

And how do I enable fastboot again?

Comment: change your BIOS to go directly to Windows, find the partition with GRUB on it and reformat it/delete/whatever from Windows (make sure you have the right one, otherwise you'll stop Windows from booting), and as for "fastboot", if you mean "fast startup" in Windows, you can do that from control panel -> power options -> choose what the power buttons do -> change settings that are currently unavailable -> turn on fast startup (recommended). If you disabled some fast booting option in BIOS, you can re-enable it there.